How to use Rotativa.AspNetCore in Blazor Server
I am using .net 8 and working on a Blazor Server project, I want to add Rotativa.AspNetCore and I would like to know what are the steps to convert a .razor view to PDF. My intention is to call from a button in a view "a" and obtain the pdf of a view "b" in a new tab.
One last rotating question, does it work for .cshtml files as well as for .razor files?
My Controller
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Rotativa.AspNetCore;

public class PdfController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult GenerarPdf()
    {
        return new ViewAsPdf("Factura");
    }
}

My view "A"
@page "/Test"

<h1>Testing Factura</h1>
<h2>CBL</h2>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
    @onclick="(e) => GenerarPdf()">PDF
</button>

@code {
    private async Task GenerarPdf()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("/Pdf/GenerarPdf");
    }
}

